# .htaccess special redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two old urls:
www.example.com/catalog/... and www.example.com/catalog/b/...

I have created new ones:
www.example.com/catalogs/a/... and www.example.com/catalogs/b/...

and I would like to 301 redirect old urls to new urls.

What have I tried, but it was obviously wrong:

```
    RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ /catalogs/a/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^catalog/b/(.*)$ /catalogs/b/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Second rule was rewriting previous one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reorder the two rules. The first rule is matching requests that include the `/b/`:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/b/(.*)$ /catalogs/b/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ /catalogs/a/$1 [R=301,L]
```